# how to erase git key made by http login (VS CODE LOGIN)

Tags: git, github, key

i am new to git and have a private repository
i did cloned them in a computer which is not mine , and now that i am done i want to cut the access , but the system is still able to access all my repositories , cloning editing and pushing (full admin access)

i generated no SSH key and cloned it via HTTP , i cloned the repository using vscode and http link , then vscode asked me to sign in new windows , i did and cloning was done

there is no keys in GitHub setting "SSH and GPG key" section so I could delete .

one SSH Key which I made on desktop is now deleted and still the computer has full access to my account , I don't know if there is another one

even I uninstalled and reinstalled git in this computer exit my GitHub account from chrome and still this pc have access to my repository

how can I exit completely and destroy git keys on this PC? and OS is windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:

Go to Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager and select Windows Credentials,
then delete github.